# Checking if a texture is valid from its name

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

Is there a way to check to see if an opengl texture name set with glGenTextures has still got a valid texture associated with it? In the documentation I see there is a function glIsTexture, but it is not clear if this function returns GL_FALSE, if the texture has been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

This is... complicated.

If you have called `glDeleteTextures` on a texture name, then that name is no longer a texture... *unless* a later call to `glGenTextures` returns that name again. See, once you delete a texture, OpenGL is free to use that name later on. It's like deleting a pointer; it is possible that later memory allocations will return exactly that pointer again.

All `glIsTexture` can do is test to see if the texture is *currently* not a texture. It might become a texture again later.